# MongoDB get $lookup leftovers

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to implement a query that will merge two collections into one and this can be done using `$lookup`. What I'm trying to achieve is that if the `localField` doesn't match `foreignField` I wanted that record to be included as well. Is this possible or am I missing something? Below is what I've tried so far which is a basic `$lookup` aggregation:

```
const billPayments = await BillPayment.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          isActive: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: PackageList.collection.name,
          localField: "serviceNumber",
          foreignField: "serviceNumber",
          as: "package",
        },
      },
      { $unwind: "$package" },
      {
        $project: {
          serviceNumber: 1,
          amount: 1,
          isCaution: 1,
          paymentDate: 1,
          remark: 1,
          package: "$package",
          id: "$_id",
        },
      },
    ]);
res.json(billPayments);
```

The current result of `billPayments` is only for those `BillPayment` data which `serviceNumber` exists in both collections. But I wanted those records which don't exist in `PackageList` to be included as well. How can I achieve that?

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here. Any help is appreciated.

#Edit for expected output

```
"billPayments": [
    {
        "amount": 299.25,
        "id": "604f5bbd6bf57e1f9c58203f",
        "isActive": true,
        "isCaution": false,
        "packageService": {
          "_id": "5fc4a5e15ce5bf227451f4b8",
          "isActive": true,
          "serviceType": "Post_Paid",
          "moneyLimit": 3000
        },
        "employee": {
          // Employee data from Employee collection to be included
        }
        "paymentDate": "2021-03-14T21:00:00.000Z",
        "remark": "",
        "serviceNumber": "0935998681"
      },
      {
        "amount": 299.25,
        "id": "604f5bbd6bf57e1f9c58203f",
        "isActive": true,
        "packageService": {
            //   If there is no match for serviceNumber
        },
        "paymentDate": "2021-03-14T21:00:00.000Z",
        "remark": "",
        "serviceNumber": "0735448621"
      }
  ]
```

Edit for additional `$lookup` query:

I have got a second level `$lookup` to get additional information from another collection. Which is like below:

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: PackageList.collection.name,
      localField: "serviceNumber",
      foreignField: "serviceNumber",
      as: "package",
    },
  },
  { $unwind: "$package" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: Employee.collection.name,
      localField: "package.employee",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "employee",
    },
  },
```

As @DheemanthBhat suggested in his answer, I've tried to remove `unwind` from `Package` and can easily get an empty list. But if I tried to `$lookup` on `Package` to get the employee information, it throws `MongoError` since it cannot lookup on an empty object.

Is there any method to skip those `empty` packages from a second level `$lookup`? Or how can I use `$ifNull` in this case to skip `$unwind` from empty results?

Comment: Why not $merge into one of the collections directly?

Comment: @Yahya can you show me how? I'm pretty new to mongoDb

Comment: If you show me sample documents, I should be able to put together something

Comment: @Kirubel also included the expected output plz.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat I've edited my question with the expected sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you perform `$lookup` without [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) all the details from `BillPayment` collection matched or unmatched with the `PackageList` collection will be available. If you `$unwind` then the documents with empty `packageService` will be removed. Based on your expected output If you want an empty `packageService` object then check the below query.

**Note**: Please verify the collection/model name and field names before using the below code.

```js
const billPayments = await BillPayment.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { isActive: true }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "PackageList",
      localField: "serviceNumber",
      foreignField: "serviceNumber",
      as: "packageService"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      serviceNumber: 1,
      amount: 1,
      isCaution: 1,
      paymentDate: 1,
      remark: 1,
      package: "$package",
      id: "$_id",
      packageService: {
        $ifNull: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$packageService", 0] }, {}]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/15/2021, 6:36:05 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604f5bbd6bf57e1f9c58203f"),
    "isCaution" : false,
    "amount" : 299.25,
    "paymentDate" : ISODate("2021-03-15T02:30:00.000+05:30"),
    "serviceNumber" : "0935998681",
    "id" : ObjectId("604f5bbd6bf57e1f9c58203f"),
    "packageService" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fc4a5e15ce5bf227451f4b8"),
        "serviceNumber" : "0935998681",
        "isActive" : true,
        "serviceType" : "Post_Paid",
        "moneyLimit" : 3000
    }
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/15/2021, 6:36:05 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604f5bbd6bf57e1f9c582040"),
    "isCaution" : false,
    "amount" : 300,
    "paymentDate" : ISODate("2021-03-16T02:30:00.000+05:30"),
    "serviceNumber" : "0735448621",
    "id" : ObjectId("604f5bbd6bf57e1f9c582040"),
    "packageService" : {
        
    }
}
```

Test data:

`BillPayment` collection

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604f5bbd6bf57e1f9c58203f"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "isCaution" : false,
    "amount" : 299.25,
    "paymentDate" : ISODate("2021-03-15T02:30:00.000+05:30"),
    "serviceNumber" : "0935998681"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604f5bbd6bf57e1f9c582040"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "isCaution" : false,
    "amount" : 300,
    "paymentDate" : ISODate("2021-03-16T02:30:00.000+05:30"),
    "serviceNumber" : "0735448621"
}
```

`PackageList` collection

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc4a5e15ce5bf227451f4b8"),
    "serviceNumber" : "0935998681",
    "isActive" : true,
    "serviceType" : "Post_Paid",
    "moneyLimit" : 3000
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but it says MongoError on my side

Comment: I figured it out, the error was happening coz I have a second `$lookup` query on an empty object. Is there any way to use `$ifNull` before a second `$lookup` query?

Comment: Yes. I can help if you update the question with your attempt.

Comment: I've also tried to use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false` to include empty packages as well but unable to skip the `$lookup` query.

Comment: Hey I tried very hard to reproduce your issue, but I am not getting any error for the `$lookup` style we are using.